# Python Voice Transcription Missing Words / Phrases

Tags: python, voice-recognition

I'm using a Google Voice Transcription Function from this package

```
def find_speech_regions(filename,frame_width=10, min_region_size=1, max_region_size=5):  # pylint: disable=too-many-locals
    """
    Perform voice activity detection on a given audio file.
    """
    reader = wave.open(filename)
    sample_width = reader.getsampwidth()
    rate = reader.getframerate()
    n_channels = reader.getnchannels()
    chunk_duration = float(frame_width) / rate

    n_chunks = int(math.ceil(reader.getnframes()*1.0 / frame_width))
    energies = []

    for _ in range(n_chunks):
        chunk = reader.readframes(frame_width)
        energies.append(audioop.rms(chunk, sample_width * n_channels))

    threshold = percentile(energies, .25)

    elapsed_time = 0

    regions = []
    region_start = None

    for energy in energies:
        is_silence = energy <= threshold
        max_exceeded = region_start and elapsed_time - region_start >= max_region_size

        if (max_exceeded or is_silence) and region_start:
            if elapsed_time - region_start >= min_region_size:
                regions.append((region_start, elapsed_time))
                region_start = None

        elif (not region_start) and (not is_silence):
            region_start = elapsed_time
        elapsed_time += chunk_duration
    return regions
```

My function basically transcribes mp3 to text but this function is always leaving out words / not picking them up
Was wondering if any coders who work with sound or transcription could help me out :)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I haven't use this API, but one of the reasons might be the hyperparameters (frame_width, min_region_size, max_region_size) or the model has some threshold and does not output anything if the confidence of the model is below a certain value.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.